# problem redirecting page from login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi
Below is the code i m using for login page.but it does not enter to button click.and when i tried to put new button, its button click event opens in aspx page.
I m not getting where exactly the problem is.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string password = "";
    string query = "select AdminPwd from tbladminlogin where AdminId='" + txtUserName.Text + "'";
    MySqlConnection objMyCon = new MySqlConnection(strProvider);
    objMyCon.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, objMyCon);
    MySqlDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (r.Read())
    {
        password = r[0].ToString();
    }
    if (password == "")
    {
        Session["Login"] = false;
        lblMessage.Visible = true;
        lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Username";
        txtUserName.Text = "";
        txtPwd.Text = "";
    }
        // 
    else
    {
        if (txtPwd.Text == password)
        {
            Session["Login"] = true;
            Session["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;

            Response.Redirect("concertDetail.aspx");
        }
        else if (txtPwd.Text != password)
        {
            Session["Login"] = false;
            lblMessage.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "Invalid Password";
            txtPwd.Text = "";
        }
    }
    objMyCon.Close();
}
```

//aspx page

```
<div id="login">
    <%--<div class="response-msg success ui-corner-all">
                        <span>Success message</span>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit
                    </div>--%>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="email" class="desc">
                Username:
            </label>
            <div>
                <%--<input type="text" tabindex="1" maxlength="255" value="" class="field text full" name="email" id="email" />--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" MaxLength="255" Width="470px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="password" class="desc">
                Password:
            </label>
            <div>
                <%--<input type="text" tabindex="1" maxlength="255" value="" class="field text full" name="password" id="password" />--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPwd" runat="server" MaxLength="255" Width="470px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="buttons">
            <div style="position: relative; top: -4px; left: 408px; width: 67px; height: 32px;">
                <div style="position: relative;">
                </div>
                <%--<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all float-right ui-button" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" type="submit">Login</button>--%>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to format your Code.  Also try to only post the smallest understandable portion for us to look at.

Comment: Aren't you using asp.net login control for this?

Comment: also put asp:Label inside form tag otherwise the page wont compile

Comment: Firstly you are opening yourself up to a SQL Injection attack here, by concatenating the query string the way you are. Please use a parametrised command. Secondly if you are comparing the password directly with what is input in the textbox then you cannot be hashing the password in the database. That again is very bad practise.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in your method (to ensure it never executes)?

Comment: I agree with @Ira Rainey

Comment: Right said by @naveen. Put lblMessage inside the form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onclick event below searches for a function "btnSubmit_Click" in javascript and not code-behind, since the button is an html control:

```
<button class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all float-right ui-button" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" type="submit">Login</button>
```

As for as the asp:Button is concerned, it should work. There doesn't seem to be any problem in it. Please check that the ASP.NET Development server is not already running. Next clear your cache and check if debugging is enabled in your browser.

As far as the double click issue is concerned, you should disable it. The best solution to this, in my knowledge is to deal with it on client-side like this:

```
<script>
    var reqSubmitted = false;
    function submitRequest() {
        if (!reqSubmitted) {
            reqSubmitted = true;
            return reqSubmitted;
        }
        reqSubmitted = false;
        return reqSubmitted;
    }
</script>
```

........................................

```
<form id="Form1" runat="server" onsubmit="return submitRequest()">
```

Comment: debugging is enabled.and this line  is commented out.i have take asp button.

Comment: @user755230, I know that html button is commented out. I was just telling the reason why it wasn't working initially. Besides, what do you mean by  "when i tried to put new button, its button click event opens in aspx page"? Do you mean that the button click event in code-behind is executing? On which line are you getting the exception, while debugging? Also where is "strProvider" defined?

Comment: all that is in .cs file.but when i double click on button it should open function to write code in .cs file but it opens in .aspx file in <script> tag

Comment: @user755230. The problem is due to the double click functionality, which should be disabled. Check my updated solution for that and let me know if it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
 <form id="Form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="btnSubmit">
```

instead of

```
 <form id="Form1" runat="server">
```

and as said before please use [parametrized query](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) to avoid sql injections and other many problems.